# Не клонируется проект с гитхаба, из директории проекта магически пропадают папки

Tags: android, git, github, gradle

Проблема: когда клонирую свой проект с гитхаба, почему-то в директорию назначения приходят только *папка .git и два файла (README и LICENSE)*.
Остальные папки (app, в которой весь код проекат и все файлы связанные с Gradle) просто не доходят.

Может кто-то знает в чем соль?

Я пользуюсь приложением *Github Desktop*.

PS Вообще все началось с того, что неделю назад у меня внезапно из папки пропали все файлы проекта и те что с пометкой Gradle (не могу точно сказать после чего, так как я просто работал как обычно, писал код и тестировал на телефоне). Причем не только от этого проекта, а еще двух других, хотя остальные проекты, что в той же папке, остались целостными. Я как-то смог их восстановить с гитхаба (уже не помню как) а все что не успел пушнуть - пришлось писать заново. Сегодня снова эти файлы пропали. Пытаюсь заклонировать с гитхаба, но доходят вот только вышеперечисленные файлы *README, LICENSE и папка .git*, которые похоже и так не пропадали. Буду благодарен за любые пподсказки.

Comment: ветки проверяли? Может вы перенесли весь код в другую ветку, а в масте осталось то, что осталось?

Comment: что то мне кажется, что это связано с переходом master->main. То есть, случайно нажали какую то кнопку, оно ветку переименовало, но как то плохо. Github Desktop по умолчанию видимо берет main. а весь код в master

Comment: Спасибо, действительно проблема с открытием клонированного была частично связана с ветками. А вот причину почему изначально файлы пропадают пока не понял. Если что, создам отдельный вопрос.